# The website hosted on EC2 not able to access S3 image link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have assigned a role of Fulls3Access to EC2. the website on EC2 are able to upload and delete S3 objects but access to the s3 asset url are denied(which mean I can't read the images). I have enable the block public access settings. Some of folders I want to make it confidential and only  the website can access those. I have tried to set conditions on public read like sourceIp and referer url on bucket policy, but below doesn't work, the images on website still don't display. Anyone have ideas to enable and also restrict read s3 bucket access to the website only?

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/assets/*",            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIP",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/private/*",
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "ip1/32",
                        "ip2/32",                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify this part? "I have enable the block public access settings". So can you say which of "block public xxx" is ON and which is OFF? All of them should be OFF unless something changed in the UI. I cannot see anything obviously wrong on the bucket policy. Instead of the IP address condition it's better to give access to the private section to a role which is assigned to the instance via an instance profile. But that does not cause the public access problem.

Comment: Thank you Petrch. The "block public access" in ON. by turning it off, it solve the read access problem. Now my problem is how to restrict the access to certain prefixes. What do you mean by private section? is it a VPC for private subnet?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I meant "to the private section of you bucket" i. e. `bucketname/private/`. So if your instance has an instance profile, you can allow access based on the role of the ec2 instance. That's much more flexible. I googled for this example https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/instance-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks @petrch, let me test this. the link is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to serve these assets in the users browser via an application on the EC2 host then the source would not be the EC2 server, instead it would be the users browser.

IF you want to restrict assets there are a few options to take whilst allowing the user to see them in the browser.

The first option would be to [generate a presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) using the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). This will create an ephemeral link that will expire after a certain length of time, this would require generation whenever the asset would be required which would work well for sensitive information that is not access frequently.

The second option would be to add a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of the S3 bucket, and use a [signed cookie](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html). This would require your code to generate a cookie which would then be included in all requests to the CloudFront distribution. It allows the same behaviour as a signed URL but only requires to be generated once for a user to access all content.

If all assets should only be accessed from your web site but are not considered sensitive you could also look at adding a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to a CloudFront distribution in front of your S3 bucket. This would be configured with a rule to only allow where the "Referer" header matches your domain. This can still be bypassed by someone setting that header in the request but would lead to less crawlers hitting your assets.

More information is available in the [How to Prevent Hotlinking by Using AWS WAF, Amazon CloudFront, and Referer Checking](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/) documentation.

Comment: Thank you Chris for clearing my confusion. These are really good answers and exactly what I am looking for.